# How to harden apt with seccomp in Debian 10?

Tags: debian, apt, sandbox

[Here](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#apt-sandboxing) it says "*[...] APT [...] can make use of seccomp-BPF sandboxing*" and describes how to do so only by:

> APT::Sandbox::Seccomp is a boolean to turn it on/off

That's a bit sparse imo. Where should this option go? Why can't it be changed in some GUI options of for example Apper? Can apt-config be used for it? Or where should this setting go? Into some file in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/? `grep -R APT::Sandbox:: /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` doesn't show anything.

Comment: All the `apt::` options go in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or other files in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`. Why some gui doesn't support it is upto whoever develops the GUI. `apt-config` is used for querying options, not setting them, so no idea what you want to use it for here.

Comment: That file doesn't exist on my machine. Which other file in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d?

Comment: You can create it if you want. Or whatever file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`:

```
echo 'APT::Sandbox::Seccomp "1";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99seccomp
```

You can then check the setting using `apt-config dump`.